# Calling an Actionresult in another Actionresult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two Actionresults, EditInfo and CreateNew.

```
public ActionResult CreateNew()
        {
            ActionResult _view = EditInfo(0)
            return _view;
        }
public ActionResult EditInfo(int? ID)
        {
            if (ID == 0)
            {
                EditModel obj = new EditModel();
                return View(obj);
            }
             EditModel obj = new EditModel();
                ......
            return View(obj);
        }
```

When i choose the option CreateNew, i should display the view with empty fields. If i choose  the Edit option, I should display the view with current values of fields. EditModel has parametes like Name, Age etc.. I have tried this using the code above. Its not working. Iam new to asp .net. Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: how do you select CreateNew or EditInfo?

Answer (score 1):

### `Calling an Actionresult in another Actionresult`

you can use `RedirectToAction`

```
       public ActionResult CreateNew()
        {
            ActionResult _view = EditInfo(0)
            return RedirectToAction("action name","controller name","params");
           //this will go to second action;
        }
```

Comment: I tried this. Iam even getting the display. But the layout of the view that is getting displayed is different from my EditInfo view.

Comment: @user3363329 layout is defined in the view itself like Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; check the layout in the views

Comment: the parameter i pass here is 0. Can u pls tel me my below return statement correct?: return RedirectToAction("EditInfo","User",0);

Comment: is this ActionResult _view = EditInfo(0) needed??

Comment: @user3363329 no that is not